# How to access sqlite database from app widget?

Tags: android, sqlite, widget

DBHelper is the database helper class that creates the database. It has a method getTimetable that returns a Timetable object. when I use it in the main activity it works fine and returns the proper Timetable object. I pass in (this) as a context parameter when creating DBhelper. But when I'm trying to run it in the widget updateAppWidget method it crashes the system I think it happens that I dont pass the same context as I did in the main activity.

```
static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId) {

    String daysFull[] = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};

    DBHelper myDB = new DBHelper(context);
    Timetable t = myDB.getTimetable();
    //t.getTimeSlot(daysFull[Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK],(new Date()).getHours()+":00")
    TimeSlot ts = null;
    String text = "";
    System.out.print(t.toString());
    if (t != null) {

        int hourCount = (new Date()).getHours();
        while (hourCount < 22) {

            if (t.getTimeSlot(daysFull[Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK], hourCount + ":00") != null) {

                ts = t.getTimeSlot(daysFull[Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK], (new Date()).getHours() + ":00");
                break;
            }
        hourCount++;
    }
    System.out.println("hello hello hello");
    if (ts != null) {

        text = ts.getStartTime() + "\n" + ts.getModule() + "\n" + ts.getRoomNumber();
    } else {

        text = "No More Classes\nFor Today";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today is sunday so I get 7 from the Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK and so when daysFull[Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK] is called its pointing to non existing variable and craches...

so I used daysFull[Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK]-1 instead...

Answer (score 0):

AppWidget and your application have a different context, you can use ContentProvider

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html

> A content provider is only required if you need to share data between multiple applications